# I have created a mongodb (employee) with its collection (Employee, transaction) and my query is to increment salary of all employees using update cmd

Tags: database, mongodb, collections, field, document

Update salary of all employees by giving an increment of Rs. 4000.

```
db.Employee.update({ },{$inc:{salary:4000}})

WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,**
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
            "code" : 14,
            "errmsg" : "Cannot apply $inc to a value of non-numeric type. {_id: ObjectId('61d5d566b13d4952b5aebac8')} has the field 'salary' of non-numeric type string"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you get says:

> Cannot apply $inc to a value of non-numeric type ...  'salary' of non-numeric type string

So you have a document with a `string` salary, What you can do is cast the `salary` field to the right type first, here is an example using `$ifNull` and `$toInt` to do so ( note that this still expects `salary` to be a valid numeric string, if `salary` is `"abc"` then this update will also fail ).

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      salary: {
        $sum: [
          {
            "$toInt": {
              "$ifNull": [
                "$salary",
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          4000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true,
  
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FnqztZn2_a3)